# How to pop selected row from material data table?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using material data table for my Angular project. I use a dynamic table, where data gets added and deleted. How do I pop a given row from the data table?
Of course pop doesn't work. I also used `splice(row, 1)`, which also didn't work (maybe I used it wrong).

Type of 'row': Row is an object (Array consisting of 4 numbers).

Log of the row:

```
{sender: "7", recipient: "1", amount: "1", fee: "1"}
```

When clicking on the checkbox (each row has a checkbox) in the data table I want to delete the row. The checkbox determines, which row is getting deleted:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); putTXInBlock(row);"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Where the row should get deleted:

```
  putTXInBlock(row) {
    this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
    this.temp.pop(); // pop input parameter row
    this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    this._TS.emitTransaction(row);
  }
```

Comment: What type is `row`? `row: string`, `row: number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice` to remove an element from an array at an index.

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.temp.length; i++){
      if(JSON.stringify(row) === JSON.stringify(this.temp[i]) ){
        this.temp.splice(i,1);
        break;
      }
  }
```

To your question, you can't `pop()` because `pop()` can only remove the last element in the array.

Comment: I tried it with splice. It still deletes the first row always.

Comment: log the value of row you are getting, are you sure its not 0 always?

Comment: That's better, row is not a number, it's an object... What is the id of the row?

Comment: What do you mean with id?

Comment: row has sender, receipient, amount and fee. Out of these 4, which one or which ones should be used to indentify the row in the temp array?

Comment: Updated answer, it should do because row is a simple object.